# npm wouldn't install core-js module when installing React

Tags: reactjs, npm

here's the error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Users\rezki\OneDrive\Bureau\stage ipact\wetransfer_ordear-admin-webapp-develop-1-rar_2023-08-07_0908\-ordear-admin-webapp-develop (1)\-ordear-admin-webapp-develop (1)\-ordear-admin-webapp-develop\-ordear-admin-webapp-develop\-ordear-admin-webapp-develop\node_modules\core-js       
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being ab
```

I tried many things including setting the PATH variable for cmd.exe and nothing worked.

Comment: try clearing the cache `npm cache clean --force`. also make sure that ur project (path) does not contain some special, weird and long names as by the looks of things `C:\Users\rezki\OneDrive\Bureau\stage ipact\wetransfer_ordear-admin-webapp-develop-1-rar_2023-08-07_0908-ordear-admin-webapp-develop (1)-ordear-admin-webapp-develop (1)-ordear-admin-webapp-develop-ordear-admin-webapp-develop-ordear-admin-webapp-develop` is not a good name, is hella long and potentially contains some characters that npm do not like in the path